# Can groovydoc handle the autogenerated get/set methods?

Tags: groovy, groovydoc

I have a library I wrote in groovy, and I would like to make it available for Java users. When I use groovydoc to generate documentation, however, it doesn't include any of the get/set methods for my class properties. Is there a way to make it generate that?